# Use Xcode 4 subversion integration with custom port?

Tags: svn, xcode4

I have to connect to my workplace's subversion. The ip is open on a specific port. I have tried to connect with Tortoise from my Win 7 laptop and it works just fine, so I guess the subversion server and repository is all right.

When ever I insert the IP to the subversion server the Repository-wizard in Xcode 4 says it can connect (to the server). But when ever I put the custom port number after with ":" between it cant checkout from subversion.

The url I want to connect to is: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx

The Ip only should work since it says "Host is reachable", but with the port specified the wizard says "Host is unreachable".

I'm terrified with the thought that Apple only made the subversion integration work on default port. - Thats just typical Apple.

Any ideas please, on how to connect to subversion using a specific port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced almost the same problem, excepting that I even could not get "Host is reachable" message with any part of my URL. I found several possible reasons and several solutions, such as:

- XCode sends local user's credentials and SVN cannot authorize user; You should try to execute any svn command from terminal with no credentials and, when it asks, enter right ones;
- XCode cannot work with SVN on custom port; You should change SVN port to default;

But none of them worked for me. But finally I managed to get things work. You just need to create an alias for your IP in **hosts** and use that alias in URL instead of IP. A comprehensive manual of how to make aliases you can find [here.](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-in-mac-os-x-leopard/) At the end my URL looked like *http://svnserver:8080/svn/...* and everything works just fine.

Good luck!

Comment: We have our svn server on our local network. I don't understand why adding this IP to my hosts file fixed anything, but it worked, so that's great, but why did Apple break it, it worked perfectly fine in Xcode 3...

Comment: It would solve the problem, but i found a much better way. SVN integration in Xcode 4 really sucks (try to add a file and after that rename it and you're screwed.) So basically i just downloaded the SvnX which is very cool GUI for Subversion on MAC. Another way is to just use Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

for svn im using SCplugin http://scplugin.tigris.org/ that works great.