# After upgraded to Xcode 4.2, Organizer - SVN repository stopped working

Tags: macos, svn, xcode4, xcode-organizer

I recently upgraded my Xcode to 4.2. Since then my Organizer-Repository stopped working. Initially it said "Host is unreachable" and placed red dot every where.

In the same Mac 10.6.8, i do have SvnX and it works with same SVN location without any problem. I also tested this in Safari and found it is working (Server supports VisualSVN). Only Xcode is finding problem with this location.

I even appended my private/etc/host files with 
svn.ip.address   my-svn-pet-name 
and used that in my xcode following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699721/use-xcode-4-subversion-integration-with-custom-port). Doesn't work.

My repository is connected over a specific port 8080. I gave ip-address in svn url as http://my-svn-pet-name:8080/...

Any help is highly appreciated.

UPDATE: To isolate the issue, i tried to connect http://gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ from xcode organizer and it works without any problem. I didn't supply any user-name and password for this location. However, my repository requires authentication, in my recent tries when i select the short-cut on left pane, the dot-icon next to trunk, branches and tag glows green. However, when i click 'root' and tried to expand 'trunk' it says 'Unable to load revisions'

UPDATE 9/9/11: Uninstalled xcode using command sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all and Restarted the mac and Re-installed Xcode 4.2.

When i open Organizer, contrary to my expectation, all svn shortcuts are intact and the issue still persists.

Comment: I've been having the same problem and silversurfer's answer worked fine for me.

Comment: I too suppose that something is broken with Xcode svn code. However similar to 'silversurfer' I went to terminal and use svn command directly, it asked me about what I wanted to do with untrusted certificate, I stored them permanently and svn start working within Xcode also.

Comment: This worked for me after much of this post didn't:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904939/xcode-4-2-svn-issues

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problems are only with the latest XCode 4 (build 4C177 — iOS 5 beta 7).

A slightly earlier version of XCode 4 (build 4C104 — iOS 5 beta 5) works fine.

Like Saran, I tried the suggestions from majkelx and OMH and they did not work for me.

When I launch build 4C177, and immediately open the Organizer, the repositories initially show green (as Saran noted) and histories are available. Any other operation turns them red. But the comparison view in the text editor *successfully* shows diffs against the repository, with revision number.

So, I conclude that the repositories are set up OK and authentication is actually working, but various source-control functionality in build 4C177 is buggy. I'd advise installing an earlier XCode 4 and waiting for the next release. I filed a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Thank you ZeroDiv. I guess this could solve my problem as well. But i couldn't find a way to reach previous versions. Can you please give me some steps to reach?

Comment: Well I took the URL for the current iOS SDK:

Comment: Just now I copied the URL for the current iOS SDK, changed the "preview_7" to "preview_5", and "beta_7" to "beta_5", and it started downloading a .dmg.

I don't want to post the full URL of either version because Apple might not approve.

Perhaps beta 6 worked as well, I don't know. If this helps you, don't forget to vote me up; my StackOverflow reputation could sure use a boost. (Maybe I should try answering more questions!)

Comment: I reduced my xcode preview level and ends up with Build 4C151a. But it didn't work. I left it that way for the past few days. When i again checked today, i found xcode working with my intranet svn. Not sure what went between my downgrade and now. I believe downgraded might also helped it.

Answer (score 5):

1. Close Xcode and all of Subversion clients
2. Go to Keychain Access.app
3. Search for all 'svn' entries.
4. Delete all which can be related to your repository (assuming that you remember users and passes)
5. Checkout project from the command line (Terminal.app) (to be sure, I use svn which goes with Xcode in the example below, may be You have installed another svn command line from macports or sth?)

   > ```
   > /Developer/usr/bin/svn co  http://my-svn-pet-name:8080/... tmp-dir
   > ```
6. Provide users and passes when svn asks for them.
7. Go to Keychain Access.app again and for newly created entry (search for svn again) in details/Access Control, give access to password for all apps (this's not needed in 99% of cases but can fix issues with svn versions and other subversion clients mismatches).
8. That's it. Xcode should see your repositories again, or after recreating shortcuts to them in Organiser.

Comment: I tried this but didn't solve my problem. I removed and recreated short cuts several times during my trouble shooting. At times, it lists trunk, branches and tags folder and on the right shows green dot next to trunk, branches and tags. That indicates, i assume, it was able to reach svn this time. However, when i clicked trunk on the left, it says "Unable to load revisions". My "Refresh" doesn't make any difference. Please let me know if you have any further suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: I had an svn entry for my local repository in the key chain.  Xcode 4.2 shows the UserID and password in the Repository UI.  After I had this problem, I changed these and changed them back to see if that made a difference.  I didn't close Xcode and removed the entry from my keychain.  I did not use the command line or change the credentials in Xcode (they were already correct).  When I clicked on my trunk, it all loaded quite nicely at that point.  I double checked  my key chain and there were no entries for svn any longer. HTH.

Answer (score 3):

Tried everything, "Host is unreachable" all the way.

The following fixed it instantly for ME (using a https connection(!)):

- Enter your repo address in Safari (only server address might work, as well).
- When Safari warns you about trusting the server, "always accept" the certificate.
- Restart Xcode. Done. Works.

Answer (score 2):

I have been having the same issues, starting with beta_7 (previous betas of 4.2 did not exhibit the issue).  I upgraded to the GM of 4.2, and still the same.

I discovered what was happening in my situation.  The URL endpoints I've been used are SSL (https://my-svn/etc/etc).  When I logged in via Safari to test, I was being presented with the "cert might not be valid" warning, then I continued past this and was able to enter my creds and could see the repository structure (as expected).

I initially thought that the cert being used on the server had expired, and Xcode was honoring the warning behind the scenes.  Next time I tried with Safari, I chose the "View Certificate" in the warning, and saw that the cert was still fresh (2018 expiration date), but that our self-signed cert was not pointing to a Certificate Authority, and Safari was reporting that my Mac did not trust that cert.  So, I chose the "Always trust" options that are presented by the dialog, and the warnings went away in Safari.  The "forced trust" is established in the Mac's Keychain, so then I launched Xcode and viola, all of the associated repository entries in Organizer glowed green.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using VisualSVN.

I could connect to is over `HTTPS://mysvnserver:8443/` where I then was requested for a user/pass combo.

In Xcode the connection always failed. Sometimes Xcode would complain about the certificate not being issued by a trusted authority, which in my case would be correct.

The certificate is in my keychain as always trust but that didn't solve the issue.

My solution:

1. open an terminal window
2. type command `svn co https://mysvnserver:8443`
3. A request is issued for the certificate security press P to allow permanent.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4.2's SVN is well and truly broken.

svn from the command line works just fine, so I don't see how it can be an authentication issue -- it's just a straight bug and a demonstration of how much testing Xcode releases receive these days... The Xcode 4 series has been a lot of backwards :-(

SVN in Xcode 4.1 was *almost* working properly.... And now it doesn't work at all. Whee!

Answer (score 1):

When you use any IP to access SVN, XCode sends local user's credentials and SVN cannot authorize user;

You just need to create an alias for your IP in hosts and use that alias in URL instead of IP. A comprehensive manual of how to make aliases you can find [here](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-in-mac-os-x-leopard/). At the end my URL looked like `http://svnserver:8080/svn/...`.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. The dots are green in the list of repositories but it just refuses to commit changes or update status, though compare works fine.

I opened Repositories, then on the left pane selected the project under the repository item. In the bottom-left of the window you'll have two buttons, Update and Commit. I pressed Commit there and it worked fine. However, after that it still wouldn't commit through the project (Alt+Cmd+C or through File menu). Not sure exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Xcode 4.2, I had the same problems, red dots, and "host unreachable".

I tried the recipe from majkelx, but those dots where still red.

But then I just tried to check out the repository with the Xcode organizer instead of the command line. And suddenly it all worked!

(It may not have worked without fiddling with the Keychain, like majkelx described)

EDIT: When searching for Subversion entries in keychain, also seach for "sub", not just "svn". My passwords where in "subversion". Only my web subversion password was in "svn".
Just one more hint for others who are struggling with this. I wasted more than an hour on this today. :-)

Comment: It appears i am not as lucky as you. Tried your suggestion, the problem still persists. I am also having the feel that it has to do with credentials. If the credentials it uses doesn't work (whatever xcode remembers), shouldn't that give me a dialog to enter? Even that is not happening. Anyway, Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Try **remove the "https://login@"** from your svn address
Works for me.

for `http://my-svn-pet-name:8080/` try something like `my-svn-pet-name:8080/`

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue, with Xcode 4.2 (Build 4D199) being able to connect initially (green lights) then losing connection shortly after (red lights). But this only happens when I am connected to the same LAN as the SVN repository using a cable. If I switch to a wireless connection, Xcode is able to connect again (green lights). In all cases I am able to ping and connect to SVN using the terminal and other SVN tools. It is just Xcode that struggles. You could try going wireless or through VPN to bypass this problem.