# Xcode 4 organizer repository view changes says "No Version Editor"

Tags: macos, svn, xcode4

My prior problem was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203553/after-upgraded-to-xcode-4-2-organizer-svn-repository-stopped-working).

Now, when i see change logs and click view changes, the pop-up comes but right pane just tells "No version editor".

My search couldn't yield any solutions suitable to this. Any suggestions or solutions to this problem? Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was gone after i installed the public version of Xcode 4.2 with iOS 5. Mine is Mac OS Leopard.