# Setting up SVN repository in XCODE 4.2

Tags: macos, svn, xcode4

I am having issue in setting up SVN repository in my XCODE 4.2. When I am setting up repository path XCODE always shouts that the host is not reachable.

The same path is reachable from XCODE 3.2.6.

Am I missing anything in setting up in XCODE 4.2?

Comment: This post should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203553/after-upgraded-to-xcode-4-2-organizer-svn-repository-stopped-working

Answer (score 2):

There **is** a bug in XCode 4.2, i filed a radar and was closed as duplicate... so it's implicitly confirmed by Apple.
I'm talking about the GM version of Xcode, not a Beta!

Comment: I'm also experiencing this bug in Xcode 4.2 GM.  SVN was mostly working for me in Xcode 4.1.

Comment: Yeah, everybody has the same problem in 4.2 GM, please file a bug report so maybe it gets fixed faster!!!

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, there's a problem accessing repositories using ip adresses. Try using hostname instead...

Comment: Even host name does not help. I think there is bug in 4.2 Beta 7 version of XCODE.