# Rails server no longer runs: no such file to load -- savon (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rvm, activesupport

I have a brand new MacBook Pro, purchased circa May 1, 2012.  At the time of my purchase, apparently there are issues with C compiler in Xcode which meant that GCC had to be installed for rails to work. So my current set up includes:

Homebrew

Rails 3.2.2

RVM

Ruby 1.9.3-p0 for current project

ZShell ( oh-my-zsh)

Git and GitFlow

Xcode

GCC

The current project that's failing is a Rails 3 project that uses Ruby 1.9.3-p0

I've Googled extensively and looking throughout stackoverflow, and I've seen people with similar problems but something that seems to be this same problem.

After four hours of searching I finally decided to post here.

**Here's the problem:**

I can't run rails on this project. This is a project that's been cloned from a repo. The project runs fine on my Ubuntu machine with the same version of Rails and the same ruby version.

I CAN create and scaffold in a new Rails project from scratch fine. But this particular project: Can't even start a rails server. When I do, I get this following cascase of errors which I'm having trouble figuring out:

```
rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/JohnConq/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-     3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': no such file to load -- savon   (LoadError)

from /Users/JohnConq/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport- 3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
```

.... and so on. Other errors are just a cascade of problems triggered by initial error.

So I looked in dependencies.rb on line 251 and its simply the second line within this function : ( the line that begins with load_dependency )

```
def require(file)

    result = false
    load_dependency(file) { result = super }
    result
end
```

So I'm not really sure what is being passed to that function to trigger the error.

It's funny because this project WAS working on this same Mac machine yesterday. Yet after an Xcode update everything seemed to start failing. I re-installed GCC and hoped that would fix it, but no luck.  I deleted the gemset in RVM after re-installing GCC and then did a bundle install , thus creating a new gemset. Still doesn't work.

I'm at my wits end. This project was just running yesterday on this same Mac. I don't know what's wrong.  Any ideas ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: what is savon?  seeing as that is the apparent source of the initial error,  what can you tell us about savon?  Is it in the Gemfile?  can you find it anywhere in the source of the project that won't boot?

Comment: It's funny because the Savon gem is not located ANYWHERE in the project from looking at the Gemfile and talking to our CTO.  So something weird is happening here.

Comment: Have you tried a global search for 'savon' anywhere in the project?  Seeing as things went south AFTER the Xcode update,  it sounds to me like it is related to the Xcode upgrade.  I would google 'Xcode upgrade'.  I did so and found some problems, i.e. 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203553/after-upgraded-to-xcode-4-2-organizer-svn-repository-stopped-working'

Comment: Yeah I totally uninstalled Xcode via command line and all the developer tools dependencies and it's still coming up. So weird. Savon isn't even in the project AT ALL

Comment: OK NEW INFORMATION: this may be compiler related errors based on my inability to install ruby version properly. When I try to install a new ruby version , it "seems" to install ok , but I get errors that are dumped into a log .... those error I have pasted below:

Comment: [2012-05-07 09:31:15] tar xmzf /Users/JohnConq/.rvm/archives/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz -C /Users/Nmuta/.rvm/src 
yaml-0.1.4/tests/example-reformatter-alt.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/tests/example-deconstructor.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/tests/test-reader.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/tests/Makefile.am: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/tests/test-version.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/tests/run-dumper.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might have permission problems, try:

```
sudo rm -rf /Users/JohnConq/.rvm/*/yaml* /Users/JohnConq/.rvm/usr/
sudo chown -R JohnConq /Users/JohnConq/.rvm/
```

Also to make sure you have proper GCC - install osx-gcc-installer